# Javascript underscore every always return false

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using the every function from the underscore library but it always returns false

```
. _every( Anarrayid, (key) =>{
                  mydataset.has(key)});
```

I have an array that contains Ids and a set that also has a collection of ids but returns false. I have tried comparing as sets but again same problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think this line is valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I'm using the lambda syntax from emca6

Comment: @RocketHazmat, that is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Shouldn't it be `key => { mydataset.has(key) }`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. It should be at least: `_.every(Anarrayid, (key) => mydataset.has(key));`

Comment: It on the one hand is a syntax error and if you would use `key => { expression }`  then you are missing a `return` (`key => { return expression; }`. Or you need to omit the `{}` and write `key => expression`

Comment: @RocketHazmat, ah yes it should.

Comment: Sorry error my part as I was writing this from memory on train on my way home.  Dan is correct as this the syntax I am using but is always false

Comment: remember, mydataset should have a key for every id in Anarrayid.

Comment: It does because it is effectively it is a copy

Comment: @Andy5: What are `mydataset` and `mydataset` defined as?  I made a quick example, and your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/eLutp4zy/

Comment: Mydataset.is defined as a set which contains unique guids,  file name,  and a couple of hrefs. The array is exactly same

Comment: I am thinking that the array and set are seeing data as the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way is the following:

```
_.every( Anarryid, key => mydataset.has(key) )
```